# Is Cuda Toolkit release 11.7 compatible with pytorch version 11.6?

Tags: pytorch, cuda

I have installed recent version of cuda toolkit that is 11.7 but now while downloading I see pytorch 11.6 is there, are they two compatible?

Answer (score 5):

There is a table with CUDA compatibility:
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

At this moment the latest supported CUDA version is 11.6.